# Phonegap built application looks different than when run on phonegap developer app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

Hi I'm having some problems with my phonegap app. When running the app on the phonegap app on my phone it works perfectly but when I build the app it looks completely different, the css is disregarded and everything is hugely downsized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a common problem; output on a simulator looks different to the final outcome on the intended target. It's best to only use a simulated environment as a testing area to ensure there are no errors. Always check on the final environment to discover any potential UI problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add the cordova [console plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) in your config.xml if you are building your app using [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com) like this:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"  />
```

After uploading the app's source code to [build.phonegap.com](https://build.phonegap.com) go to the app's Settings and check the "Enable debugging", save the settings and Rebuild your app.

[image]

After building the app, download and install it on your device and attach your device via a cable while "Debug Mode" enabled on your device. Now open the Chrome Browser and type following the new tab:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

As soon as you will start your app in the device it will start appearing here in the tab. Just click the "inspect" link and it will open up the console for you. There you can debug your app. Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks! That's helping me to debug, but do you have any idea why the jQuery Mobile theme css isn't working, but only when the app is built?